# Unable to query deleted EventRelation records with ALL ROWS

Tags: soql, isdeleted

The `EventRelation` object has an `IsDeleted` field, which implies that I should be able to query for deleted records.  However, I'm not seeing that.  After manually removing an invited contact from an Event, I cannot find the deleted record.

This is the POC code I'm using in a scratch org with just a handful of events & EventRelations, so that I can query all records without a where clause (to eliminate one possible point of failure).  I have the System Administrator profile in the scratch org, and I own all of the involved records.

```
List<EventRelation> res = [
    SELECT id, EventId, RelationId, IsDeleted, LastModifiedDate
      FROM EventRelation
       ALL ROWS
];
system.debug(res.size());
system.debug(JSON.serialize(res));
```

I never get any records with `IsDeleted=true`, and the size of my query result decreases each time I remove an invitee.

I'm not looking to undelete, just trying to identify people removed from meetings.  As `EventRelation` doesn't support triggers, I cannot run code upon deletion.  How to I query these deleted records?

**Update**: I also tried running the query from Workbench with the "include deleted & archived records" option, just to see if a different API would get different results, but I'm still not able to see an EventRelation I deleted only seconds before.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?  This is exactly what I am facing so it is still an issue in fall of 2023.

Comment: @WardWood Not that I recall, but that was 5 years and 1 job ago.  I don't recall what we ended up doing, but I don't think I ever found a way to track this information.  If you have the ability to open a developer support case (Premier support, Partner Portal), it might be worth asking Salesforce for input.